# count the number of appearance of a string in each column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, function, count

I have a dataframe with the string "name" appearing and I want to count the appearance of it for each column. I would like the results in a new df.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'first_column':  ['1', '2', 'name'],
        'second_column': ['name', 'name', 'name'],
         'id_number':['name', '4', 'name'],
        'fourth_column':['5', 'name', '2'],
        }


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

[image]

I tried this but this gave me this output but I don't have a new df and have too many results:

```
for col in df1:
  df2 = df1[df1[col] == "name"].count()
  print(df2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for equality for the entire dataframe, then call `sum` on it, and since you need it as a dataframe, you can call `to_frame` at last:

```py
>>> df1.eq('name').sum().to_frame('count')

               count
first_column       1
second_column      3
id_number          2
fourth_column      1
```